# Rename Dataframe columns based on cell values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to rename column names within a dataframe based on some combining multiple cell values (strings) which are at specific index points in the dataframe.

I have tried using loc and iloc to signify the cell values that I want to be added and named to the new index names.

```
OverallA1Y.columns = ['Overall Research Rank', 'Weighed Comm Rank', 'Analyst Name', 'Firm', 
                      'Weighted Comm Score', 'Overall Research Score', 'Weighed Comm Firm Vote Count',
                     OverallA1Y.loc[5,7]+OverallA1Y.loc[6,7], 'Weigted Comm Vote Count', 
                      'Overall Research Firm Vote Count']
```

The error that I receive is:

```
TypeError: cannot do label indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [7] of <class 'int'>
```

Any idea on how to concatenate/combine multiple string values and rename the column accordingly?

Thanks

Comment: One idea, do you need select by positions with `OverallA1Y.iloc[5,7]+OverallA1Y.iloc[6,7]` ?

Comment: @jezrael iloc worked! very simple little things.Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for seelct by positions instead `loc`:

```
OverallA1Y.iloc[5,7]+OverallA1Y.iloc[6,7]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
OverallA1Y.columns = ['Overall Research Rank', 'Weighed Comm Rank', 'Analyst Name',
                      'Firm', 'Weighted Comm Score', 'Overall Research Score',
                      'Weighed Comm Firm Vote Count',

                       str(OverallA1Y.iloc[ROW_INDEX_OF_CELL][COLUMN_NAME_OF_CELL])+
                       str(OverallA1Y.iloc[ROW_INDEX_OF_CELL][COLUMN_NAME_OF_CELL]),


                      'Weigted Comm Vote Count', 
                      'Overall Research Firm Vote Count']
```

Comment: The problem in your code was accessing the cell value and second, convert your cell values so that they can be concatenated. Hope it helps thank you.